# Can you set a Python class instance member variable to be a Cython object?

Tags: python-3.x, cython

Can you set a Python class instance member variable to be a Cython object? Is this possible?

If that is not possible, can we set a Python class instance member variable to be something which points to a Cython object?

Comment: I think the answer is "yes, why don't you just try it and see?" but it really isn't clear what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by "class instance member variable" and "Cython object." I'll assume this rewording is what you mean:

> Can you set a member variable of a pure Python class to be a Cython `cppclass` instance?

No. Pure Python instances can have Python references to other Python instances. At the C layer this means that the `__dict__` can contain `PyObject*` pointers, but not generic C or C++ pointers to structs that don't obey the `PyObject*` semantics.

In Cython, you can use the `cppclass` keyword to create new C++ classes that are not `PyObject` variants (`cdef cppclass CppClassDefinedInCython: ...`). They're C++ classes like you'd create in a `.h` file.

Cython also allows you to declare new `class` objects (`cdef class PyObjectClassDefinedInCython: ...`). Under the hood, these are classes whose first set of fields have the same memory layout as all `PyObject` C structs and obey the pure C `PyObject` semantics. If you `cdef` fields in that class, then you can have the class contain arbitrary C and C++ data structures that are available to the C or C++ code generated by Cython.

If you're mixing C or C++ code with Python using Cython, you'll want to look up some tutorials such as: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html